# Pickling a Complicated Trained FeatureUnion in Python

Tags: python, pickle, pipeline

I have a complicated featureunion consisting of several pipelines with custom transformers and standard transformers.

I am trying to pickle a fit featureunion for subsequent use but I'm getting errors.

I fit and pickle my featureunion as follows:

```
# Pickle fit pipeline

feature_union = feature_union.fit(X_train)

pickle.dump(feature_union, open("feature_union.p","wb"))
```

elsewhere I load the pickled featureunion and try to transform new data like this:

```
# Open fit pipeline and transform new data

feature_union = pickle.load(open("feature_union.p","rb"))

X_validation_enc = feature_union.transform(X_validation)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-7b78df603a5a> in <module>
      1 # Open fit pipeline
      2 
----> 3 feature_union = pickle.load(open("feature_union.p","rb"))
      4 
      5 X_validation_enc = feature_union.transform(X_validation)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'column_selector' on <module '__main__'>
```

The pickle works when I have the entire featureunion, pipeline and transformer code in the 'new' (destination) script.  Does that mean the only thing I can pickle is the the fit featureunion object?  The error suggests I need all the code in the new script and all I'm loading is a fit featureunion object so the only 'savings' is that I don't need to fit the featureunion on training data.  Is this correct?  Is there some way to pickle so I can remove all the featureunion/pipeline/transformer code in the new script?

My featureunion consists of numerous custom and 'library-based' transformers and actions.  In some instances I pass outside lists and variables into the class (tranformer).  All of these lists and variables are present in the new code.

At a loss.

If it helps, the structure of my featureunion, pipelines, and some code for the transformers is shown below.

Guidance appreciated.

The structure looks like this:

```
feature_union = FeatureUnion([
                         ('cat_binary', pipeline_categorical_binary),
                         ('cat_ordinal_string', pipeline_categorical_ordinal_string),
                         ('cont', pipeline_continuous)
                        ])
```

One of the pipelines has this structure:

```
pipeline_continuous = Pipeline(steps = [
        ('column_selector', column_selector(numeric_features)),
        ('numerical_impute', numerical_imputer(numerical_impute_approach)),
        ('continuous_transform', continuous_transformer(continuous_transform_dict,do_transform)),
        ('scaler',DFStandardScaler(perform_scaling))
       ])
```

Within the pipeline, I have custom and packaged transformers. For example, the 'continuous transform' custom transformer referenced in the above pipeline log transforms data and looks like this:

```
# 3 Transform continuous features    

class continuous_transformer(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, type_transform, do_transform ='No'):        
        self.do_transform = do_transform
        self.type_transform = type_transform
            
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
         return self
    
    def transform(self, X):

        if self.do_transform == 'Yes':
            for key, value in self.type_transform.items():
                if value  == 'log_transform':
                    X[key] = X[key].apply(lambda x: np.log(x+1.0))  
                    X.rename(columns = {key:'log_' + key}, inplace = True) 
            X_continuous_transformed_df = X
            return X_continuous_transformed_df
        else:
            return X
```

And the 'scaler' transformer uses the `StandardScaler` module and looks like this:

```
# 3 Standardize continuous features    

class DFStandardScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, perform_scaling):        
        self.ss = None
        self.perform = perform_scaling
                
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.ss = StandardScaler().fit(X)
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        if self.perform == 'Yes':
            Xss = self.ss.transform(X)
            X_continuous_scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(Xss, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
            return X_continuous_scaled_df
        else:
            X_continuous_scaled_df = X
            return X_continuous_scaled_df
```

The above hierarchy is well defined in my code.